# setup.py: linebreak in 'description'

Tags: python, setup.py

I want to include the `import` statement in a separate line of my short description.

```
setup(
    name='my-module',
    packages=find_packages(),
    license='MIT',
    description='A useful module. \nfrom my_module import MyModule',
    long_description=README,
    long_description_content_type='text/markdown',
)
```

However, once I include the `\n` character in my description, I get the following error in my *long description* upon running `twine check dist/*`:

```
Checking dist\mymodule-1.0-py3-none-any.whl: FAILED
  `long_description` has syntax errors in markup and would not be rendered on PyPI.
    line 7: Error: Unexpected indentation.
  warning: `long_description_content_type` missing.  defaulting to `text/x-rst`.
Checking dist\mymodule-1.0.tar.gz: FAILED
  `long_description` has syntax errors in markup and would not be rendered on PyPI.
    line 7: Error: Unexpected indentation.
  warning: `long_description_content_type` missing.  defaulting to `text/x-rst`.
```

Apparently the linebreak character in the setup.py is not parsed correctly - is it generally not possible to have a linebreak character in the description or do I have to use it differently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [python setuptools docs](https://docs.python.org/3.8/distutils/setupscript.html#additional-meta-data) specify that the `description` field must be a "short string". That might sound like generic english but that has a semantic significance, as described soon afterwards-

> ‘short string’
>
> A single line of text, not more than 200 characters.

And there lies the problem. The string must be a **single line** (no newlines) - and must also be at most 200 characters.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have newlines/linebreaks in your (short) `description=`.

It's surprising, at least the checker behavior, but it's a known issue and as for November 2020 [it's being solved](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/1390)