# 'setup.py install is deprecated' warning shows up every time I open a terminal in VSCode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Every time I boot up terminal on VSCode, I get the following prompt. This does not happen on Terminal.app.

```
    /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:34:
SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip
and other standards-based tools.
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Install the **setuptools 58.2.0** version using the following command:

```
pip install setuptools==58.2.0
```

Comment: I can confirm this works, but it would be nice to solve this issue even with using the latest version of setuptools (currently 65.5.0). So your answer seems to be a workaround, not a solution.

Comment: this is helpful when I build ros2 on windows by `colcon build --merge-install`

Answer (score 28):

I assume you stumbled across this issue when you was building your `.whl`-file doing something like `python Setup.py bdist_wheel --dist-dir .`. (If not: This answer probably not applies to your problem.)
The warning you see wants to say that calling `python Setup.py ...` is obsolete now.

Solution, in short:

Replace `setup.py` with `pyproject.toml`. In `pyproject.toml` you enter all values from `setup.py` in an INI-file-like-structure. Then you create your `.whl`-file using the command `python -m build`.

Further information about python-packages and `pyproject.toml`: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/

Further information about how to use `pyproject.toml` using `setuptools`:
https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/pyproject_config.html

Answer (score 8):

Calling `setup.py` directly is being deprecated, as [explained here](https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2021/10/setup-py-deprecated.html#summary).

I did as the message told me and now **build the wheel using pip** (it still calls `setup.py` internally):

```
pip wheel --no-deps -w dist .
```

This replaced my old equivalent code:

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Note that the `pip wheel` command creates the wheel into your current directory by default, which is why I specify `-w`/`--wheel_dir` to match the old behavior of using the `./dist` directory.

I also specify `--no-deps` so pip does not download the wheel files of all dependencies.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `pip` to install setup.py.

```
pip install .
```

This command assumes that you are in the root directory of the project where the `setup.py` file is located. The `.` specifies the current directory as the source for installation.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrade the setuptools. The versions greater than 58.2.0 is not showing the deprecation warning as of Oct 18, 2022.

`pip install -U setuptools`

Note, there are many ways to package Python. You will want to evaluate where your target deployment is. Working with the `TOML` files is a trend that allows better integration with many software languages. Reference: [Overview of Packaging for Python](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/overview/)

Comment: still showing up when building with vscode

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what JialeDu says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73273307/10827244), also make sure that you use the `build` module (which you will need to install first) to build your project:

```
python -m build  # builds both sdist and wheel
```

You can read more in the official documentation:

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/commands.html

While it is true that direct install via `setup.py` is deprecated because of `disutils` [source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/distutils.html], you can still use `setup.py` for packaging purposes. `setuptools` absorbed portions of the code it dependent on from `disutils`, and is still actively maintained on [GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools).

Answer (score 0):

Install the setuptools 58.2.0 version using the following command

```
pip install setuptools==58.2.0
```

Don't upgrade the setuptools. Only the version 58.2.0 worked for me. Though I tried upgrading the version to 65.5.0 but it was showing the deprecation warning.

Comment: This answer conflicts with another answer which states the newer versions no longer have the said warning. Either has to be corrected. Please consider providing link to resources or additional documentation to support your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check your pyproject.toml for newlines. If migrating from setup.py to pyproject.toml, check your `description` line. This needs to be a short line with no newlines `\n`. Reference similar issue [linebreak in description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64770237/setup-py-linebreak-in-description)