# Building Python C module on Windows

Tags: python, c, windows, setuptools, python-extensions

I am trying to build a 'C' python extension on Windows, the core C code compiles absolutely fine, but I am unable to build the python module using setuptool as I am getting

```
mandlebrot.c(36): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory
```

error: command 'e:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2

I am trying to build using:

```
python3.9 setup.py build_ext --inplace --plat-name win32
```

Any help would be welcome as I have spent a long time trying to work out how to get this to work.

The setup file:

```
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from subprocess import getoutput

LIB_DIRS=['.\mandlebrot_set\libs']
INCLUDE_DIRS=['.\mandlebrot_set\includes']
    
module1 = Extension("mandlebrot",
                    sources = ["mandlebrot.c", "mandlebrot_python.c"],
                    libraries = ['mpfr', 'mpir'],
                    library_dirs = LIB_DIRS,
                    include_dirs = INCLUDE_DIRS)

setup(name = "PackageName",
      version = '0.1',
      description = 'Mandlebrot Set calculator',
      author = '',
      author_email = '',
      ext_modules = [module1]
)
```

Comment: You misspelled Mandelbrot.  It's "el", not "le".

Comment: I don't have experience building Python extensions. so I don't feel qualified to write an answer, but check out the second code block under https://docs.python.org/3/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils. You will probably need to add the path to your C standard library headers to `include_dirs` (exactly what the path is depends on your setup)

Comment: Your example is not reproducible. Personally, I recommend using pybind11 and scikit build.

Comment: Add the source code ([\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) and **the full build command output**. What do you mean by "*the core C code compiles absolutely fine*"?

Comment: Also, what happens if you drop *--plat-name win32*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### 1. The error

By default, *Python* is built on *Win* with *VStudio* ([[Python.Wiki]: WindowsCompilers](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WindowsCompilers)), and it also uses that to build *C* / *C++* code (unless otherwise instructed).

It seems like you don't have *VStudio*'s cross build tools (for *032bit*) installed. A quick search revealed:

- [[SO]: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h' - Visual Studio Community 2017 - C++ Error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44219901/4788546)
- [[MSDN.Social]: how to resolve fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdio.h': No such file or directory](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/d707dd65-a4d6-448f-a2ed-1c182ac2a07e/how-to-resolve-fatal-error-c1083-cannot-open-include-file-stdioh-no-such-file-or-directory)

My installation (*Visual Studio Installer*) looks like:

[image: img0]

1. Make sure you have installed:

   - The build tools
   - At least **one** *Windows SDK* version
2. Try building a simple *Hello World* application ([[MS.DevBlogs]: C++ Tutorial: Hello World](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cpp-tutorial-hello-world)) for *032bit* (*Win32*)

   Some *VStudio* links that might help:

   - [[SO]: Visual Studio NMake build fails with: fatal error U1052: file 'win32.mak' not found (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73167842/4788546)
   - [[SO]: LNK2005 Error in CLR Windows Form (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34777349/4788546)
   - [[SO]: Calling Python function with parametrs from C++ project (Visual Studio) (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972756/4788546)
   - [[SO]: How to include OpenSSL in Visual Studio (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32158521/4788546)
3. Once the build works, try again the extension
4. If any of the 2 previous steps still fails, you might think of repairing (or even reinstalling - as a last resort) your *VStudio* installation

##### 2. Setup

Since there are files not provided for a *MCVE* ([[SO]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)), I'm going to use some from [[SO]: How to create python C++ extension with submodule that can be imported (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76294693/4788546) (latest one that I worked on involving extension modules).

I also want to point out *setup.py* deprecation ([[SO]: 'setup.py install is deprecated' warning shows up every time I open a terminal in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73257839/4788546)), but I'm not going to insist on that.

*setup.py*:

```py
#!/usr/bin env python

import os
from setuptools import Extension, setup


# @TODO - cfati: Use sources from the other SO question
SOURCE_DIR = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))), "q076222409")

# Define the extension module
extension_mod = Extension("parent",
                          sources=[os.path.join(SOURCE_DIR, "custom.cc")])

# Define the setup parameters
setup(
    name="parent",
    version="1.0",
    description="A C++ extension module for Python.",
    ext_modules=[extension_mod],
)
```

I have 2 separate *dir*s for *064bit* (*pc064*) and *032bit* (*pc032*) builds <sup>***(1)***</sup> (you'll see later why).

##### 3. Build for *pc064*

This is native (or direct) build, as (*CPU* and) default *Python* installation (that I'm going to use) is *pc064*.

**Output**:

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076249589\pc064]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b ..
> pc032
> pc064
> setup.py
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Build for pc064
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ..\setup.py build_ext --inplace
> running build_ext
> building 'parent' extension
> creating build
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409
> C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ie:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\Include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpe:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076
> 222409\custom.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\custom.obj
> custom.cc
> creating e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076249589\pc064\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
> C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10 /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\lib\x64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22000.0\\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_parent build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\custom.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\parent.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-am
> d64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\parent.cp310-win_amd64.lib
>    Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\parent.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\parent.cp310-win_amd64.exp
> Generating code
> Finished generating code
> copying build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\parent.cp310-win_amd64.pyd ->
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> build
> parent.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Try importing in Python pc064
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys;print(sys.version);from parent.child import hello;print(hello());print(\"Done.\n\")"
> 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
> Hi, World!
> Done.
> ```

So far, so good.

##### 4. Build for *pc032*

This is cross build (as host and target architectures don't match).

According to [[Python.Docs]: Creating Built Distributions - Cross-compiling on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/builtdist.html#cross-compiling-on-windows) (**emphasis** is mine):

> To cross-compile, you must **download the Python source code and cross-compile Python itself for the platform you are targeting** - it is not possible from a binary installation of Python (as the .lib etc file for other platforms are not included).

Although it's old, and the other way around it also applies (partially) to our situation.
As explained in the (build related) *URL*s above, when building for *Win*, the linker needs the *.lib* files (*${PYTHONCORE}.lib* in our case) for the target architecture, so they are required to exist on the host, and also *setup.py* (*SetupTools*) needs to find them.

**Output** (I'll reuse this console):

> ```bat
> [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076249589\pc032]> sopr.bat
> ### Set shorter prompt to better fit when pasted in StackOverflow (or other) pages ###
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b ..
> pc032
> pc064
> setup.py
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Build for pc032
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ..\setup.py build_ext --inplace --plat-name win32 -L"e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test0\libs"
> running build_ext
> building 'parent' extension
> creating build
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow
> creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409
> C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x86\cl.exe /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ie:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\include -Ic:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\Include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\include -IC:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22000.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\include\10.0.22000.0\\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um" /EHsc /Tpe:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076
> 222409\custom.cc /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\custom.obj
> custom.cc
> creating e:\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076249589\pc032\build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
> C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\bin\HostX86\x86\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test0\libs /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10\libs /LIBPATH:c:\Install\pc064\Python\Python\03.10 /LIBPATH:e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\PCbuild\win32 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\ATLMFC\lib\x86 /LIBPATH:C:\Install\pc064\Microsoft\VisualStudioCommunity\2022\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.35.32215\lib\x86 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\lib\um\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22000.0\ucrt\x86" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\\lib\10.0.22000.0\\um\x86" /EXPORT:PyInit_parent build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\custom.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310
> \parent.cp310-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\parent.cp310-win_amd64.lib
>    Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\parent.cp310-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-310\Release\Work\Dev\StackExchange\StackOverflow\q076222409\parent.cp310-win_amd64.exp
> Generating code
> Finished generating code
> copying build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-310\parent.cp310-win_amd64.pyd ->
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> build
> parent.cp310-win_amd64.pyd
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Success! But its name doesn't seem right. Try importing in Python pc032
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys;print(sys.version);from parent.child import hello;print(hello());print(\"Done.\n\")"
> 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 19:43:38) [MSC v.1934 32 bit (Intel)]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'parent'
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Try importing in Python pc064 (this also seems wrong)
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys;print(sys.version);from parent.child import hello;print(hello());print(\"Done.\n\")"
> 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 20:01:21) [MSC v.1934 64 bit (AMD64)]
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
> ImportError: DLL load failed while importing parent: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
> ```

**Notes**:

- The *.pyd* name is the same as for *pc064* case, which is not correct (this is why I used 2 *dir*s (check note <sup>***#1.***</sup>), otherwise the *pc064* *.pyd* would have been overwritten). Check:

  - [[SO]: What does version name 'cp27' or 'cp35' mean in Python? (@WayneWerner's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37028661/4788546) for naming details
  - [[SO]: How do I determine if my python shell is executing in 32bit or 64bit mode on OS X? (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50053286/4788546)
  - [[SO]: Python Ctypes - loading dll throws OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57297745/4788546) for the encountered error

Things are definitely wrong, could be a *SetupTools* bug (maybe fixed in later versions), this might not be the case on your side. Simplest way is to rename the *.pyd* (there might also be a *setup.py* argument?).

**Output** (continued):

> ```bat
> [prompt]> ren parent.cp310-win_amd64.pyd parent.cp310-win32.pyd
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> dir /b
> build
> parent.cp310-win32.pyd
>
> [prompt]>
> [prompt]> :: Try importing in Python pc032
> [prompt]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc032_03.10_test0\Scripts\python.exe" -c "import sys;print(sys.version);from parent.child import hello;print(hello());print(\"Done.\n\")"
> 3.10.9 (tags/v3.10.9:1dd9be6, Dec  6 2022, 19:43:38) [MSC v.1934 32 bit (Intel)]
> Hi, World!
> Done.
> ```

Worked like a charm!

This is the most generic way of doing things, and it should work for any target build (*pc032*, *aarch64*, *arm32*), once the cross build tools and the appropriate *.lib* files are present on the host machine.
**But, if aiming for *pc032* (*win32*) only, there's a shortcut**:

1. Download and install the *pc032* *Python* (which runs on *pc064* machines)
2. Use it (like in ***#3.***) to build natively