# SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py

I'm getting this error while i'm trying to install a setup.py file using this command :
python setup.py install
Some people said downgrading Setuptools will solve this error so i tried to do that but still didn't work
i'm using using python3 and i tried two versions of Setuptools 58 and 60

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['setup.py install is deprecated' warning shows up every time I open a terminal in VSCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73257839/setup-py-install-is-deprecated-warning-shows-up-every-time-i-open-a-terminal-i)

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove this message from *your* `setup.py` file, you could do so by using `warnings.filterwarnings` function, like this:

```py
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
```

Look at this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14463362/13779092) by someone else.